# asp.net - web app vs web site - code behind

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

I have a asp.net website that was built a while back. I have went through the process of converting it with visual studio into a web app. Now that I have it converted I am having some trouble using classes from a class library that is added to the project. The code behind is slightly different (below). Can anyone give me suggestion on a solution.

--to clearify a little
I have 3 visual studio projects

1 class library (data access layer)
1 class library (business logic layer)
1 website (presentation layer)-> which I converted into a web app project. with a process similar to this ([here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project.aspx))

I have a static method inside of the business logic layer that I can no longer access from the code behind in my presentation layer.

---- Web site -- /Profile/Default.aspx

```
using MyBusinessLogic;
public partial class Profile_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyBusinessLogic.Profiles.GetUserInfo(UserName);
    }
}
```

---- Web app -- /Profile/Default.aspx

```
using MyBusinessLogic;
namespace WebApplication1.Profile
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyBusinessLogic.Profiles.GetUserInfo(UserName); <---ERROR "can not access method on namespace"----------------------
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Now that I have it converted I am having some trouble using classes from a class library that is added to the project` ... what?

Comment: Profiles do not work out of the box with Web Apps as they do with Web site projects.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  What trouble are you having?  Specifically what behavior do you expect and what exactly is happening that's different?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I am not using the built in asp.net profiles. I do my own profile management in the data base. My website project has an library that is added to the project. It is used for the business logic layer. I am having trouble accessing the classes from the added business logic layer.

Comment: Isn't this simply a case of adding a using statement to the namespace where your classes are located?

Comment: thats what i would think but i do have the "using MyBusinessLogic;" added at the top of the codebehind.

Comment: pls GetUserInfo declaration?

Comment: Did you add reference to library from web application? Or maybe GetUserInfo is private?

Comment: it is public and there is a reference.

Comment: but calling GetUserInfo(UserName) is not inside any method?

Comment: apologies for my poor example. GetUserInfo(UserName) is inside of a method and that is where the error occurs. It seems to be a problem the new naming convention of a web app conflicting with my logic layers similarly named classes.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue in conversions. Please check for similar namespaces (Mybusinesslogic.Profiles) if you have resharper, just write profile.getuserinfo and check if it resolves to your correct business logic assembly or you have another duplicate existing in current namespace.